# update with sub-query error You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables, (URL and VOTE).
I need to count all the votes in VOTE and include the result in the URL table
I have tried to do it as follows but it gives me error ** You can't specify target table 'url' for update in FROM clause**

```
UPDATE url
set up = (select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote v WHERE v.id = u.id AND v.note = 1 ) as num from url u)
```

How could you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple subquery:

```
UPDATE url u
    SET up = (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM vote v
              WHERE v.id = u.id AND v.note = 1
             ) ;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to be referring to `url` in the subquery.

Comment: url -> url u (alias pmited in the orignal answer)